# Why my androind SDK floder have not Tools floder?

Tags: android, flutter

Why my androind SDK floder have not Tools floder ?
and i very confused about build-tools and platform-tool, is the same ?.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jACyI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opyOf.png)

How to get Tools floder ?, I just start to learn about android app building and im Inexperienced, Thanks you.